# Dynamodb Number datatype size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

Does dynamodb stores number datatype as string only. Whats the size of number say with value 123456. will it be 6 bytes or 4 bytes - stored as string or int in dynamodb table ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [these DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html), I believe `123456` would require **~4 bytes as a number** and **6 bytes as a string** (excluding attribute name). This is based on

1/2 bytes per significant digit * 6 significant digits + 1 byte

See quoted passage below (number entry bolded):

> DynamoDB tables are schemaless, except for the primary key, so the
> items in a table can all have different attributes, sizes, and data
> types.
>
> The total size of an item is the sum of the lengths of its attribute
> names and values, plus any applicable overhead as described below. You
> can use the following guidelines to estimate attribute sizes:
>
> Strings are Unicode with UTF-8 binary encoding. The size of a string
> is (length of attribute name) + (number of UTF-8-encoded bytes).
>
> **Numbers are variable length, with up to 38 significant digits. Leading
> and trailing zeroes are trimmed. The size of a number is approximately
> (length of attribute name) + (1 byte per two significant digits) + (1
> byte).**
>
> A binary value must be encoded in base64 format before it can be sent
> to DynamoDB, but the value's raw byte length is used for calculating
> size. The size of a binary attribute is (length of attribute name) +
> (number of raw bytes).
>
> The size of a null attribute or a Boolean attribute is (length of
> attribute name) + (1 byte).
>
> An attribute of type List or Map requires 3 bytes of overhead,
> regardless of its contents. The size of a List or Map is (length of
> attribute name) + sum (size of nested elements) + (3 bytes) . The size
> of an empty List or Map is (length of attribute name) + (3 bytes).